# Assets folder resolution: Running an application within a project not picking up assets

Tags: angular7, workspace

I created an application within an Angular workspace. When running

```
ng serve [application-name]
```

Picks up images and files in asset folder fine. Now I want to run the workspace with just

```
ng serve
```

I would expect through having the application lazy loaded the path would resolve but instead I get

```
zone.js:3243 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/terms.txt 404 (Not Found)
```

What is the proper setup to access assets of an application within a workspace?

Comment: Can you post the commands you used to create the workspace and project in the CLI and your `angular.json` file? That can help to determine what the project setup is like. Also how are you referencing the assets in your templates?

Comment: ng new sixteen-ahead
ng g library sixteen-data
ng g library sixteen-page
ng g library sixteen-login
ng g application access
ng g application crm
ng g application new

angular.json file can be found here https://bitbucket.org/tyshowers/new-sixteen/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** After talking offline I think we've found a solution. I'll post it here and leave the below for reference even though the original answer I posted doesn't really apply to the problem.

You're trying to run multiple Angular apps and route between them via something like Firebase where you can direct different routes to different apps.

To get this to work locally for development you will need to run each Angular app separately on it's own port. I suggest you control the destination of the route in the environment files. This way when you are running locally you can point to the port the app is running on and then point to the endpoint Firebase uses in production.

Example `environment.ts` file in your root app

```
{
  ...,
  OTHER_APP_URL: 'localhost:4201'
}
```

`prod.environment.ts`

```
{
  ...,
  OTHER_APP_URL: '/otherApp'
}
```

Then in your component

```js
....
import {environment} from '<path to environments file>';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<a [href]="otherAppUrl"></a>'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  otherAppUrl: string;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.otherAppUrl = environment.OTHER_APP_URL;
  }
}
```

You will probably need to do something similar in the other apps so you can route from them to the root app or other child apps. You will probably also need to build the other apps with the `--baseHref` flag when you build for production so their assets are available. See here for more info from the docs: https://angular.io/cli/build

---

**Old answer - doesn't really apply to the question**

Looking at your repo I don't see the `terms.txt` in your root project's assets folder. I checked to see if it was in one of the other libraries in the repo but wasn't able to find it there either.

If this is an asset that is included or referenced by a component or service in one of your libraries you will need to copy that over to the library's output folder as part of your build process since that functionality [isn't currently supported by the Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11317).

An example of a build script that might do this for you is:

```
ng build my-lib-with-assets --prod && cp -r projects/my-lib-with-assets/src/assets dist/my-lib-with-assets && ng build --prod
```

Don't forget that you need to build your libraries before you build your main project.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. terms.txt is part of the "access" application. So when I run the application standalone "ng serve access" everything works great. Now if I run the workspace with "ng serve" I get 404 on terms.txt